# Обработка QEvent конкретного виджета

Tags: c++, qt, события

Есть такой виджет:
[image: виджет]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно обработать `mousePressEvent` только если клик произошел по виджету `headerWidget`, как это можно сделать не перегружая его?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите перехватчик событий:

```
headerWidget->installEventFilter(headerClickHandler);
```

где `headerClickHandler` — это переменная-экземпляр класса с временем жизни не меньше чем у `headerWidget`. Сам же класс-перехватчик должен быть унаследован от `QObject` и обрабатывать все необходимые события внутри своего [`eventFilter()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter):

```
class HeaderClickHandler : public QObject
{
    // Q_OBJECT не нужен — мы не работаем с сигналами и слотами

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
    {
        // Так как mousePressEvent() — это лишь тонкая обёртка, вызываемая при
        // поступлении события QEvent::MouseButtonPress, то мы можем ловить
        // событие напрямую
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
        assert(event);
#endif
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
        {
            // Неявно предполагаем, что единственный перехватываемый объект —
            // это headerWidget

            // ... (производим все необходимые действия)

            // Позволяем передать сообщение далее, обработчику headerWidget-а
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. Мне по срабатыванию данного события нужно сделать некие действия в с CsGroupView. Как это лучше сделать? Эмитить сигнал и отлавливать его в этом классе?

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg, `Эмитить сигнал и отлавливать его в этом классе?` — что вы имеете в виду? Если обработка производится в каком-то методе `HeaderClickHandler`, что мешает вызвать этот метод напрямую из `eventFilter`?